# Vue3 + axios: how to cancel specific dynamic AJAX requests?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I have a project with many pages (components) where each page is making multiple long AJAX requests. I need to cancel SOME of them in a specific moment in time (switching between pages).

When I was using Vue2 + vue-resource I was able to put all my xhrRequests into array

```
Vue.http.get(url + action, {
   params: params, 
   before: function (xhr) {
      Vue.xhrRequests.push(xhr)
  }
}).then((response) => {
  helper.success(response)
}).catch(function (error) {
  helper.failure(error)
})
```

and anytime I wanted I could iterate over this array and cancel requests I wanted to cancel. Decision about which requests to cancel was made based on request URL.

```
  for (let i = 0; i < Vue.xhrRequests.length; i++) {
    if (Vue.xhrRequests[i].url.indexOf('news') >= 0 && Vue.xhrRequests[i].url.indexOf('select') < 0) {
      Vue.xhrRequests[i].abort()
    }
  }
```

Now I am migrating to Vue3 and I need to use axios or Fetch API (or anything else). I know I can use `signal` or `source` approaches, but when I have a lot of pages (components) and each page is making different requests it's getting tricky.

UPDATE:
I tried to use axios interceptos

```
axios.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
   console.log(config)
   return config;
}, function (error) {
   return Promise.reject(error);
});
```

but I can't see URL in config :/

Any ideas?

Comment: Doesn't this do the trick? https://github.com/axios/axios#cancellation

Comment: "but I can't see URL in config" - it's there, otherwise it would be impossible to make a request. So you need to add cancellation tokens to requests and collect them. You can use fetch instead of axios but it's raw and it will be your responsibility to provide it with interceptor functionality (there are higher level libs like Ky that do this)